# Make URL from 1 field available to another field [Drupal 8]

Tags: theming, 8

Drupal 8 Twig question:

I have 2 fields: textfield and a linkfield.

When the linkfield is filled, the text entered in the textfield should become the link.
I cannot edit the node.html.twig for this, I want to do this in the field--textfield.html.twig to include the URL (if it is set).

But I don't know how to make the URL from "field--linkfield.html.twig" available in "field--textfield.html.twig"

*(Needed because the link module is still a little bit broken in Drupal 8 (no optional URL possible)).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a field value from another field in a field template you have to use the parent entity (in your case a node) `element['#object']`:

```
{{ element['#object'].field_textfield.value }}
```

or a url from a link field:

```
{{ element['#object'].field_linkfield.0.url }}
```

Comment: Perfect! Now I know what to look/learn for in Twig :) thanks a lot!